# Make Array to have two list of data

Tags: asp.net, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc, jagged-arrays

I am using mvc5, .net 4.5
I have two variables which contains list of data
The data in both the variables are fetched from two tables respectively
when i debug the variable data1, which consists of data like

```
[0] = {value1 = "place1", money = 100}
[1] = {value2 = "place2", money = 200}
[2] = {value3 = "place3", money = 300}
```

then i debug second variable data2, which contains data like

```
[0] = {value2 = "product1", money = 100}
[1] = {value1 = "product2", money = 200}
[2] = {value1 = "product3", money = 300}
```

i want both the variable in an array because the action is called by ajax. the code is given below

```
public JsonResult Process()
{
    var data1 = fetch from table1;
    var data2 = fetch from table2;
    data[][] =  .. i dont how to do this
    --i want data like = data{data1, data2}
    return Json(data);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This smells like your business logic is wrong.. Or you can combine all the data in a single query, or you should retrive it in different calls because the data is unrelated..
Anyway, read the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Comment: `return Json(new { data1 = data1, data2 = data2 });` and then you can loop through each collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a new class that defines your new data-type:

```
public class MyData
{
   public List<Data1> Data1 {get;set;}
   public List<Data2> Data2 {get;set;}
}
```

And return it as a json:

```
public JsonResult Process()
{
    var data = new MyData
    {
        Data1 = fetch from table1,
        Data2 = fetch from table2
    };

    return Json(data);
}
```